# Extracting group from regex in shell script using grep

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

I want to extract the output of a command run through shell script in a variable but I am not able to do it. I am using `grep` command for the same. Please help me in getting the desired output in a variable.

```
x=$(pwd)
pw=$(grep '\(.*\)/bin' $x)
echo "extracted is:"
echo $pw
```

The output of the `pwd` command is `/opt/abc/bin/` and I want only `/root/abc` part of it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dirname` to get the path and not the last segment of the path.

Comment: I have made a modification, the last part bin is not a file but a directory so there is an error saying `/opt/abc/bin: is a directory`.

Comment: The error you are seeing is from the `grep` command which you are using incorrectly. grep expects a file not a directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
x=$(pwd)
pw=`dirname $x`
echo $pw
```

Or simply:

```
pw=`dirname $(pwd)`
echo $pw
```

Comment: The lack of proper quoting should also be fixed; `echo "$pw"`.

Answer (score 1):

All of what you're doing can be done in a single `echo`:

```
echo "${PWD%/*}"
```

`$PWD` variable represents current directory and `%/*` removes last `/` and part after last `/`.

For your case it will output: `/root/abc`

Answer (score 0):

The second (and any subsequent) argument to `grep` is the name of a file to search, not a string to perform matching against.

Furthermore, `grep` prints the matching line or (with `-o`) the matching string, not whatever the parentheses captured.  For that, you want a different tool.

Minimally fixing your code would be

```
x=$(pwd)
pw=$(printf '%s\n' "$x" | sed 's%\(.*\)/bin.*%\1%')
```

(If you only care about Bash, not other shells, you could do `sed ... <<<"$x"` without the explicit pipe; the syntax is also somewhat more satisfying.)

But of course, the shell has basic string manipulation functions built in.

```
pw=${x%/bin*}
```